# Channel Address Order for SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I dont see SMS Channel Address Order under contacts configuration. Due to this, I am unable to send SMS through Journey Builder.

I remember seeing this previously.

Thanks,
Susmitha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was removed in the January release, but it will not prevent you from sending SMS messages through Journey Builder. I assume that it now defaults to the mobile number priority defined for the mobile subscriber.

What issues are you having exactly? If you do not see the SMS template appear in the Send SMS Activity (on the Journey Builder canvas), you will need to ensure that you selected the 'Interaction' Send Method when you created your outbound message in MobileConnect.

[image: select interaction]

Comment: Hi Eliot,

Thanks for the reply.
  
I have one DE which is used in the Journeybuilder to send Email and SMS to the customer when the criteria is met.
   
In contact builder i have mapped Contact Key = Contact ID. 

Customer opt-in for SMS is true.

My contact enters the journey and I also see that the criteria is met, email is sent but not SMS.

Not sure where am missing.

Please help.

Thanks,
Susmitha

Comment: Your data relationship doesn't look right to me. Contact ID is a system defined key, whereas Contact Key is user defined. Have you imported your mobile subscriber data into the MobileConnect Contact List? Be aware that MobileConnect uses its own list model, and you will need to import your contacts in there too. Also, check the History page to get an indication why the SMS is failing.

Comment: Hi Eliot, I have followed your suggestion and imported data into MobileConnect list and was able to Send SMS to that List through Automation Studio. But when I am using the DE to send through Journey builder, Interaction, I am unable to send SMS

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I am unable to send SMS"? Do you see an error on the History page in Journey Builder? If so, what's the error? Can you also open Contact Builder, search for the Contact (from All Contacts) click on the Attributes tab and check that the MobileConnect Demographics attributes appear for the Contact?

Comment: With all the solution u have provided, we are able to send SMS.. Thanks Eliot